# Copy files that are N days old

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm using the current code to copy files:

```
xcopy /s /d:[date] source target
```

How do I get the date to be N days ago?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps robocopy is suitable.

```
c:\>set N=0

c:\>robocopy srcdir dstdir foo.* /MINAGE:%N% /MAXAGE:%N%
```